# Getting Day from a Date Object

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

I wanna see if someDate has any day in it. Am I checking it right?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(someDate); // someDate is a Date
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
if(day == 0){
  // code //
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you mean by "has any day in it" - all Dates will have *a* day in them... :-)

Other than that, you probably want the following:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(someDate); // someDate is a Date
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
if(day == Calendar.SUNDAY){
  // code //
}
```

The big change is that you want to get the DAY_OF_WEEK field; what your example does is gets the day within the month (e.g. September 15th would return "15").  Secondly, comparing with Calendar.SUNDAY (or equivalent) is clearer and less error-prone that directly comparing with e.g. 0, even if the code is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Every date object will have a day.  The day of the month is never going to be 0 though, it will be in the range 1-31.  Meaning that your check will always fail.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK`.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Andrzej Doyle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1525336/642706) is correct.

---

Just for the heck of it, here is that same kind of code but using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library and Java 7.

Unlike [java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), Joda-Time sensibly uses 1-based counting. So the days of the week are numbered 1 to 7. Furthermore, Joda-Time uses the standard ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)) approach where Monday is the first day of the week (1).

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

// Specify time zone rather than rely on default.
// Time Zone list… http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html  (not quite up-to-date, read page for details)
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );

DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );
if( now.dayOfWeek().get() == DateTimeConstants.MONDAY ) {
    System.out.println( "Today is a Monday." );
} else {
    System.out.println( "Nope, today is some other day of week." );
}
```